# Structuring news overview

Tags: php, templates, templatepower

I need some help with this problem, I'm having a total blackout, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I use TemplatePower as template engine. I'm tring to display my news archiv like this:

```
23-09-2013
> Update nieuwssectie
21-09-2013
> Nog toe te voegen
20-09-2013
> Nieuwe functie nieuws
> Eerste nieuwsbericht
```

But this is what I get

```
23-09-2013
21-09-2013
20-09-2013
> Update nieuwssectie
> Nog toe te voegen
> Nieuwe functie nieuws
> Eerste nieuwsbericht
```

This is the template:

```
<!-- START BLOCK : newsArchiv -->
<h6 class="newsItem">Ons nieuwsarchief:</h6>
<ul class="newsArchiv">
    <!-- START BLOCK : newsArchivDateRow -->
    <li class="newsArchivRow"><span>{date}</span></li>
    <!-- END BLOCK : newsArchivDateRow -->
    <!-- START BLOCK : newsArchivItemRow -->
    <li><a href="pagina/nieuws/{url}/">{title}</a></li>
    <!-- END BLOCK : newsArchivItemRow -->
</ul>
<!-- END BLOCK : newsArchiv -->
```

And the PHP

```
<?
$tpl2->newBlock( 'newsArchiv');
$item_sql = $sql->query( "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC" );
if( $sql->num( $item_sql ) > 0 )
{
    $date1 = "";
    while( $item = $sql->fetch( $item_sql ) )
    {
        $date2 = date( "d-m-Y", $item['date'] );
        if( $date2 != $date1 )
        {
            $tpl2->newBlock( 'newsArchivDateRow');
            $tpl2->assign( "date", $date2 );
            $date1 = $date2;
        }
        $tpl2->newBlock( 'newsArchivItemRow');
        $tpl2->assign( array(
            "url" => $item['url'],
            "title" => $item['title']
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

I just know there is a logic solution, I just can't see it and need a push in the right direction.

**[EDIT]**

Based on Bart's answer I constructed the code like this and fixed the problem.

Template:

```
<!-- START BLOCK : newsArchiv -->
<h6 class="newsItem">Ons nieuwsarchief:</h6>
<ul class="newsArchiv">
    <!-- START BLOCK : newsArchivRow -->
    <li class="newsArchivRow"><span>{date}</span></li>
    <!-- START BLOCK : newsArchivItemRow -->
    <li><a href="pagina/nieuws/{url}/">{title}</a></li>
    <!-- END BLOCK : newsArchivItemRow -->
    <!-- END BLOCK : newsArchivRow -->
</ul>
<!-- END BLOCK : newsArchiv -->
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$tpl2->newBlock( 'newsArchiv');
$item_sql = $sql->query( "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC" );
if( $sql->num( $item_sql ) > 0 )
{
    $itemsArr = array();
    while( $itemdata = $sql->fetch( $item_sql ) )
        $itemsArr[ date( "d-m-Y", $itemdata['date'] ) ][] = array( "url"=> $itemdata['url'], "title" => $itemdata['url'] );

    foreach( $itemsArr as $date => $items )
    {
        $tpl2->newBlock( 'newsArchivRow');
        $tpl2->assign( "date", $date );
        foreach( $items as $item )
        {
            $tpl2->newBlock( 'newsArchivItemRow');
            $tpl2->assign( array(
                "url" => $item['url'],
                "title" => $item['title']
                ));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Should the `$tpl2->` functions be inside the `if` statement so if date2 != date1 it outputs the url and title?

Comment: No, the code loops all the news items. When the date of the next news item is different than the date AND the news item is outputted. If the date is the same, only the news item is outputted.

Comment: When does `$date1` ever get a value to compare against `$date2`?

Comment: `$date1` is empty, the date of the first item is 20-09-2013, so `$date1` is different from `$date2` and `newsArchiveDateRow` is displayed. `$date1` gets the value 20-09-2013. 

The date of the second item also is 20-09-2013, so `$date1` is the same as `$date2` and the `newsArchiveDateRow` won't be shown.

The date of the third item is 21-09-2013. `$date1` is different from `$date2`, so `newsArchiveDateRow` is shown, and `$date1` gets the value 21-09-2013, and so on...

Comment: Is it possible that $date1 is always matching date2 because of `$date1 = $date2`within the if statement, and outside the statement you've set $date2 to the $item date? Quick thought, try echoing out the dates to see what it's setting as date1

Comment: Or move $date1 inside the while loop?

Comment: No, that is not possible, then the outputted dates would all be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know TemplatePower at all, but it looks like the template engine gets all blocks with the given name at once and renders them. If this is true you probably would need to construct the complete archive for a certain date in one block.

Comment: I guess you are right, I constucted my PHP code otherwise and got it fixed. Thanks for the push. (Also check the updated question with the code)